# cannot find library error when using gcc

Tags: c

I am trying to compile an example C program and link it to some static library files using:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -l libsundials_cvode.a -l libsundials_nvecserial.a cvRoberts_dns.c -o cvRoberts_dns.o
```

(I am sure that the library files and include files directories above are correct.)

The error I get is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsundials_cvode.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have two questions:

1) Am using the -L and -l options correctly?

2) The above error is b/c gcc is looking for the library file in the wrong location right? I tried to fix this by setting `$LD_LOAD_PATH` via my terminal to `/usr/local/bin`. I still get the above error. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

-Rohan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try -lsundials_cvode instead - delete the 'lib' and '.a' parts

Note that LD_LOAD_PATH is for locating dynamic libraries at run-time, not during compilation.

Edit:

```
I just tried that. The change addresses the cannot find library error but 
now I am faced with many "undefined reference to" errors. Does this mean 
the linking of the library files has failed somehow? How do I correct this?
```

It means that there are other symbols that need to be resolved that are not in the library you linked.  Note that you need to change both libraries (you have two on the command line).  Also perhaps they are in the wrong order.

Comment: I just tried that. The change addresses the cannot find library error but now I am faced with many "undefined reference to" errors. Does this mean the linking of the library files has failed somehow? How do I correct this? Thanks!

Comment: By "change both libraries" do you mean replace them with others? They might be resolving some symbols though, right? So, why remove them?

Comment: No I meant remove the "lib" and the ".a" on both, ie. treat them the same way.  What errors do you now have?

Comment: Ah I see. I've done that (i.e. removed "lib" and ".a" for both) which as I said fixed the "cannot find <library>" errors. Now, I am faced with the the "undefined reference to" errors. That is because, as you've pointed out, those libraries aren't resolving all the symbols. So, I need to identify the other library/ies that I need.